# Neovim asynchronous buffer waiting

Tags: vim, neovim

I am working on a Neovim plugin that interacts with a REPL in a terminal buffer. I want to be able to send a command to the REPL, copy the response, and display it to the user somehow. Currently, the terminal buffer doesn't seem to refresh output until the current vimscript function terminates, so I can't have a single function that does, eg:

```
function! plugin#eval(str)
    call s:send_to_repl(str)
    echomsg s:get_response()
endfunction
```

as the `get_response` function is working with the terminal buffer before it gets updated.

Currently, I'm using neovim's job control, though if this can be accomplished in vanilla vim, all the better.

Here's the code I'm using to initialize the terminal:

```
function! s:start_buffer(height)
    set bufhidden=hide
    set noswapfile
    set buftype=nofile
    set hidden
    terminal! stack ghci --with-ghc intero
    let l:buffer_id = bufnr('%')
    let g:intero_job_id = b:terminal_job_id
endfunction
```

Here's how I'm sending the command to the REPL:

```
function! s:send(str)
    call jobsend(g:intero_job_id, add([a:str], ''))
endfunction
```

I've tried adding an `edit` command to refresh, but that doesn't seem to work in the REPL.

The code for communicating with the REPL is [here](https://github.com/parsonsmatt/intero-neovim/blob/master/autoload/intero/repl.vim). The code for managing the process is [here](https://github.com/parsonsmatt/intero-neovim/blob/master/autoload/intero/process.vim).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `:term` buffer you can set up a `TextChanged` handler. E.g. the following code sends the entire `:term` buffer contents to `s:on_response`:

```
autocmd TextChanged <buffer> call <SID>on_response(getline(1,'$'))
```

Figuring out which text is "new" since the previous `TextChanged` event will require some custom logic. The `'[` and `']` marks aren't correctly set in the `:term` buffer (I'm not sure this is feasible for `nvim` to do automatically, but I made a [bug report](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5017)).

Note that `TextChanged` only fires if the user is in normal-mode (also immediately upon leaving insert-mode).

`TextChangedI` (notice the `I` at the end) should fire in insert-mode, but it doesn't work with `:term`, that's a [bug](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5018).

---

Another approach is to user timers (see `:help timer_start`). Here's a timer that calls `s:on_reponse(timer_id)` every second:

```
call timer_start(1000, '<SID>on_response', {'repeat':-1})
```

But this isn't ideal because you would need to keep a map of terminals and timer ids (or iterate through all `:terminal` buffers and check their contents).

---

I made a [feature request](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5023) for a `jobattach()` function which would allow attaching `on_stdout` handlers to existing jobs (whereas `jobstart()` only adds handlers to *new* jobs). This could then be used to attach to `b:terminal_job_id` of any `:term` buffer.

Comment: Hmm, the `TextChanged` `autocmd` doesn't quite do what I expect. It appears that it only fired when the user's cursor is currently located in the terminal buffer. Checking out `jobattach` now

Comment: `jobattach` doesn't exist yet--it would be a feature request.

Comment: @ephrion I added another suggestion using timers. But probably `jobattach()` is what is really needed.

Comment: @ephiron In https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5023 bfredl noted that you could use `termopen()` to attach an `on_stdout` handler just like you would with a normal `jobstart()`. So that should help as long as your plugin is in control of creating the `:term` buffers.

Comment: That's extremely helpful, thanks! I appreciate you making the feature request.